# Attribute Error : none type object has no attribute ' shape '

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, raspberry-pi3

I keep encountering an attribute error trying to read some frames from a piCamera on a raspberry pi

## Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ball-tracking/ball_tracking.py", line 48, in <module>
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 45, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'


if not args.get("video", False):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

else:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

while True:
    # grab the current frame
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()


    if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `frame` was returned as `None` in this line as if you camera couldn't read an image:

```
(grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
```

Then, when resizing a `None` object, the program blows up as we described in the error message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`:

```
frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
```

As discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043394/opencvs-video-capture-not-returning-an-image), some camera drivers may return `False, None` in the first frame. A possible workaround would be to verify whether `grabbed` is `False` and ignore this frame.

```
while True:
    grabbed, frame = camera.read()

    if not grabbed:
        continue

    # the rest of the program
```

Comment: The problem was that the V4L-2 driver wasn't in /etc/modules and so the camera could not read an image, thus the NoneType error.

Answer (score 1):

The 'NoneType' error indicated that a frame was not passed to the resize function.
When using the cv2.capture method one must ensure that the correct drivers are loaded otherwise you will end up with the same NoneType error.

The solution is to manually add the driver to etc/modules or to enter the following command:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

A simple command that loads the V4L2 drivers.